# KnockoutJS working with relations and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, knockout.js

I'm trying to get this relation to work properly. So far i've manage to "get" the relation via json, but i cant use it.

Title Model:

```
public function favorite()
{
if(auth()->check()){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Titles\UserTitle')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
}
 return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Titles\UserTitle');
}
```

Knockoutjs script, I can provide the rest of the code if you need me to:

```
handleLists: function(item, titleId) {
    var self = app.viewModels.titles.index,
    alreadyAdded = self[item]();

    app.utils.ajax({
        url: alreadyAdded ? vars.urls.baseUrl + '/lists/remove' : vars.urls.baseUrl + '/lists/add',
        data: ko.toJSON({ _token: vars.token, list_name: item, title_id: titleId }),
        success: function(data) {
            if (alreadyAdded) { 
                app.utils.noty(data, 'info');
                self[item](false);
            } else {
                app.utils.noty(data, 'success');
                self[item](true);
            }  
        }
    })
},
```

full Knockout script here: http://pastebin.com/fMN5ha1j

I'm specifically using this code in the view. it's served under a "foreach:" parameter for the data-bind

```
                    <div id="favorite" class="snippet" data-bind="click: $root.handleLists.bind($data, 'favorite', $data.id)">
                        <span data-bind="if: favorite">
                            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                        </span>

                        <span data-bind="ifnot: favorite">
                            <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

full view here: http://pastebin.com/rGa2QhJY

the if:favorite or the ifnot: favorite doesn't work

this is an example json format with the relation: http://pastebin.com/UaZVg227

Comment: You still looking into this?

Comment: yes i posted this today

Comment: Please do include a full (but *minimal* (you can't expect us to wade through all that code)) repro in the question itself. See [mcve] for guidance.